# Determining Whether Automatic Upgrade will Fail?

Tags: plugins, automatic-updates

I've been traumatized by the automatic upgrade in the past, and am fearful to ever try it again. It seems that there's no transaction logic, and when it fails, it leaves everything broken. Is there some way I can tell whether the upgrade will succeed or not based upon WordPress' ability to overwrite certain files, and whether it can make necessary changes to the database?

I'd love to be able to simply ask WordPress to test the various types of access it needs to upgrade, and then tell me whether or not those tests passed before trying to do the actual upgrade. Any solution that is capable of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if a plugin for this exists.  But make sure you correct whatever mistake prevented it from upgrading last time.  Make sure the appropriate folders are writeable.

Comment: I would love to correct any mistakes, but if I'm not wrong WordPress fails silently leaving no stack.

Comment: enable error reporting

Comment: Do these upgrades always fail or just happen once in a while?

Comment: @Lucas The only success I've had is with a smaller site which had 777 on nearly all directories. Other sites are far too large for me to attempt, and far too important for me to 777 everything. I may take it upon myself to build a plugin that checks these types of things.

Answer (score 0):

Since 3.2 WP uses new system of partial upgrades for core - only changed files get downloaded and overwritten. So probability of it messing things up is much lower.

Updates (if any) of database are actually performed after file update is done on next dashboard visit. If WP is not capable of making those, it's likely just as not capable of normal operation.